# Activating opened Excel workbook from Outlook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro in my Outlook that whenever I receive an e-mail with a certain subject, it automatically opens an Excel workbook and pastes a portion of the e-mail subject in a specific cell in one of the worksheets. It works perfectly. Now I need to do this exact same process but pasting this information in an already opened workbook, instead of opening a closed file.

I've tried different solutions from my limited Excel VBA knowledge (ActiveWorkbook, worbooks(filename).activate, etc.) but none of that worked and I have not found anything similar online, as most macros are written as being run from an Excel file and not Outlook.

This is part of our current code, that opens the file and pastes the e-mail subject (which is the "ticker" value) in a specific cell on the "Lista Empresas" worksheet. What I need is a code that does the same, but in an workbook that is already opened (let's call it "test1").

```
         Dim exapp As Excel.Application
         Dim ExWbk As Workbook
         Dim ExWbk2 As Workbook
         Set exapp = New Excel.Application
         Set ExWbk2 = exapp.Workbooks.Open("\\XXX\ListaEmpresas_ajustado.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=0)
         exapp.Visible = True

         ExWbk2.Sheets("Lista Empresas").Range("P2").Value = ticker
         ExWbk2.Sheets("Lista Empresas").Range("P3").Calculate
```

Comment: Does the open excel workbook have a fixed name?

Comment: Hi Tim. Yes, the excel workbook has a fixed name "ListaEmpresas_ajustado" and should be opened at all times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few scenarios to handle here. First, is Excel running? If no, then do what you are doing already. If yes - is the correct workbook open? If yes - return it, otherwise open it.

```
Dim ExWbk2 As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim exapp As Excel.Application

On Error Resume Next
Set exapp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set exapp = Nothing
End If
On Error GoTo 0

If exapp Is Nothing Then
    ' Excel is not running
    Set exapp = New Excel.Application
    Set ExWbk2 = exapp.Workbooks.Open("\\XXX\ListaEmpresas_ajustado.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=0)
    ExWbk2.Visible = True
Else
    ' Excel is running, but is the right book open?
    For Each wb In exapp.Workbooks
        Debug.Print wb.Name ' <-- This will help you find what to look for
        If wb.Name = "ListaEmpresas_ajustado" Then
            ' Yes, it is!
            Set ExWbk2 = wb
        End If
    Next
    If ExWbk2 Is Nothing Then
        ' No, it wasn't
        Set ExWbk2 = exapp.Workbooks.Open("\\XXX\ListaEmpresas_ajustado.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=0)            
    End If
End If
```

The trick to find out if Excel is running is `GetObject`. It will fail if it can't find it.
The for loop is there to allow for finding the correct workbook, based on the name. Adjust as needed.

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for the reply! This code is really helpful as it includes some alternative scenarios in case the workbook is not opened, thanks for that. When trying to run the code, it tries to reopen the file, although the file is already opened, so I believe it is not recognizing the file to be opened. And even if I select to reopen the file, I get a "Object doesn't support this property or method" error on the "Exwbk2.visible=true" code. Could you give me a hand?

Comment: I have now added a debug statement above. Press Ctrl+G to show the debug output before running it. After running it, you will see what names it found, Adjust the `If` below accordingly

Comment: Sam, it was missing the extension, thanks for the debugger! Now it's working! The other error on the "Object doesn't support this property or method" error on the "Exwbk2.visible=true" persists, though, when I need to open the file. Any thoughts?

Comment: Just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code gets the object if you know the name of the sheet currently active in Excel instance. I guess this could be got from the application title using the first bit of code.

```
Dim exapp As Excel.Application
Dim ExWbk As Workbook
Dim ExWbk2 As Workbook
Set exapp = GetObject("ListaEmpresas_ajustado.xlsm").Application
exapp.Visible = True

ExWbk2.Sheets("Lista Empresas").Range("P2").Value = ticker
ExWbk2.Sheets("Lista Empresas").Range("P3").Calculate
```

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks for the reply! Using this code I get the following errors: "Automation error" and "Invalid syntax". Keep in mind that I'm are running this code on the Outlook environment. Any ideas?