# Download and open Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have the following code that allows me to download the attachments of an email. I would like to open it once it is downloaded, but I can't.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
Sub DescargarAdjuntos(Message As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim Attachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim Path, archivo As String
    Path = "C:\Users\esnsanma\Desktop\Bancolombia_diarios\"
    For Each Attachment In Message.Attachments
    If InStr(Attachment.DisplayName, ".xlsb") Then
              Attachment.SaveAsFile Path & "" & Attachment.DisplayName
              archivo = (Attachment.DisplayName)
          End If
    Next
    MsgBox Path & archivo
    Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\esnsanma\Desktop\Bancolombia_diarios\" & archivo
End Sub
```

How can I open the downloaded Excel file from this same code?

Comment: All questions and answers on the main Stack Overflow site are [required to be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/205114).  Please either translate your question or try [es.so], but be sure to follow their [content guidelines](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ensure an on-topic question.

Comment: Side note: remove the parentheses from `archivo = (Attachment.DisplayName)`. Then, shouldn't the `Workbooks.Open` be *inside* the loop? Or if you only have 1 Excel attachment, then it'd be better to add an `Exit For` inside the `If...End If`.

Comment: the Workbooks.Open statement is the one that generates an error

Comment: What's the exact error message you get?

Comment: vba is being executed from an outlook vba module, that is why it generates an error, my solution was to call shell "code", because from vba outllok I cannot call excel libraries

Comment: Non-shell approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58342093/activating-opened-excel-workbook-from-outlook